# R - How to make 2 adjacency matrices compatible to eachother

Tags: r, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have 2 adjacency matrices with different dimesnsions. I want to make their dimensions compatible so that when I replace any column of one matrix from any column of second matrix then I don't get the following error message: 
**Error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**
Here are my matrices:

```
> mat1
      Tommy Roy Addy Sam
Tommy     0   1    0  -1
Roy      -1  -1    1   0
Addy      1   0   -1   0
Sam       0   0   -1   1

> mat2
     Mike Roy Addy Sam Dan
Mike    0   1    0  -1   0
Roy    -1  -1    1   0   1
Addy    1   0   -1   0  -1
Sam     0   0   -1   1   0
Dan     1   0    0  -1   1
```

To make the mat1 compatible to mat2 I have to add 2 columns and 2 rows in mat1, so that it become:

```
> newMat1
      Tommy Roy Addy Sam Mike Dan
Tommy     0   1    0  -1    0   0
Roy      -1  -1    1   0    0   0
Addy      1   0   -1   0    0   0
Sam       0   0   -1   1    0   0
Mike      0   0    0   0    0   0
Dan       0   0    0   0    0   0
```

Here 2 new column and rows have been added (`Mike` and `Dan`) as they were not there before but were part of the second matrix. Please notice that newly added rows and columns have been initialized with `0` value. Similarly newMat2 will become:

```
> newMat2
      Mike Roy Addy Sam Dan Tommy
Mike     0   1    0  -1   0     0
Roy     -1  -1    1   0   1     0
Addy     1   0   -1   0  -1     0
Sam      0   0   -1   1   0     0
Dan      1   0    0  -1   1     0
Tommy    0   0    0   0   0     0
```

Here are the original matrices dput:

```
> dput(mat1)
structure(c(0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 
-1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Tommy", 
"Roy", "Addy", "Sam"), c("Tommy", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam")))
> dput(mat2)
structure(c(0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
-1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Mike", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam", "Dan"), 
    c("Mike", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam", "Dan")))
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in question, I want to later replace the the columns between the matrices and problem is that when I do this the different ordering of colnames and rownames affect the values in the indices. for example:

```
Change <- c("Mike", "Dan")
for(i in 1:length(Change)){
 ifelse(Change[i] %in% colnames(newMat1), newMat1[,Change[i]] <- newMat2[,Change[i]], newMat1[,Change[i]][newMat1[,Change[i]] == 1] <- 0)}
newMat1
      Tommy Roy Addy Sam Mike Dan
Tommy     0   1    0  -1    0   0
Roy      -1  -1    1   0   -1   1
Addy      1   0   -1   0    1  -1
Sam       0   0   -1   1    0   0
Mike      0   0    0   0    1   1
Dan       0   0    0   0    0   0
```

Here the Mike column in newMat1 has been replaced by Mike column in newMat2. As you can see that index Mike-to-Mike is 0 in original newMat2 but it is 1 in freshly obtained newMat1, and that is because of ordering of rownames and colnames is different.

**Answer**: For this purpose ordering was required and it was done by:

```
newMat2 <- newMat2[rownames(newMat1), colnames(newMat1)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple function:

```
complete_matrix <- function(mat, ref) {
  dif <- setdiff(rownames(ref), rownames(mat))
  mat <- rbind(mat, matrix(0, length(dif), ncol(mat), dimnames = list(dif, NULL)))
  mat <- cbind(mat, matrix(0, nrow(mat), length(dif), dimnames = list(NULL, dif)))
  return(mat)
}

newMat1 <- complete_matrix(mat1, mat2)
newMat2 <- complete_matrix(mat2, mat1)
```

It first finds the missing names between the focal matrix `mat` and the reference matrix `ref`, then binds two matrices with 0s for the missing names..

```
> newMat1 
      Tommy Roy Addy Sam Mike Dan
Tommy     0   1    0  -1    0   0
Roy      -1  -1    1   0    0   0
Addy      1   0   -1   0    0   0
Sam       0   0   -1   1    0   0
Mike      0   0    0   0    0   0
Dan       0   0    0   0    0   0
> newMat2 
      Mike Roy Addy Sam Dan Tommy
Mike     0   1    0  -1   0     0
Roy     -1  -1    1   0   1     0
Addy     1   0   -1   0  -1     0
Sam      0   0   -1   1   0     0
Dan      1   0    0  -1   1     0
Tommy    0   0    0   0   0     0
```

Another solution:

```
complete_matrix2 <- function(mat, ref) {
  nam <- union(rownames(ref), rownames(mat))
  out <- matrix(0, length(nam), length(nam), dimnames = list(nam, nam))
  out[rownames(mat), colnames(mat)] <- mat
  return(mat)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please guide me how can I reorder these matrices, so that they look identical in terms of rownames and colnames?

Comment: `newMat2 <- newMat2[rownames(newMat1), colnames(newMat1)]`?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236519/replacing-for-loop-with-foreach-loop/49237000?noredirect=1#comment85479099_49237000) of replacing for loops with foreach loop or parSapply. Thanks.

Comment: HI @Axeman, I'm wondering if you can take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55735530/join-two-adjacency-matrices-and-retain-values).

Answer (score 2):

The following will do it.

```
m1 <- setdiff(rownames(mat2), rownames(mat1))
newMat1 <- rbind(mat1, matrix(0, nrow = length(m1), ncol = ncol(mat1)))
newMat1 <- cbind(newMat1, matrix(0, nrow = nrow(newMat1), ncol = length(m1)))
rownames(newMat1) <- c(rownames(mat1), m1)
colnames(newMat1) <- c(colnames(mat1), m1)

m2 <- setdiff(rownames(mat1), rownames(mat2))
newMat2 <- rbind(mat2, matrix(0, nrow = length(m2), ncol = ncol(mat2)))
newMat2 <- cbind(newMat2, matrix(0, nrow = nrow(newMat2), ncol = length(m2)))
rownames(newMat2) <- c(rownames(mat2), m2)
colnames(newMat2) <- c(colnames(mat2), m2)
```

Since the code repeats, it would be possible to write a function. If this is a one time problem, there's really no reason for it, but if you have more such problems, say so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit overkill, but here's a general solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
imap_dfr(list(mat1,mat2),~ .x %>% 
          as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F) %>%
          mutate(v = row.names(.),mat = .y) %>%
          gather(h,value,-(ncol(.)+c(0,-1))))  %>%
  right_join(expand(.,v,h,mat)) %>%
  replace_na(list(value=0)) %>%
  split(.$mat) %>%
  map(. %>%
        spread(h,value,0) %>%
        `row.names<-`(.$v) %>%
        select(-v,-mat) %>%
        as.matrix)

$`1`
      Addy Dan Mike Roy Sam Tommy
Addy    -1   0    0   0   0     1
Dan      0   0    0   0   0     0
Mike     0   0    0   0   0     0
Roy      1   0    0  -1   0    -1
Sam     -1   0    0   0   1     0
Tommy    0   0    0   1  -1     0

$`2`
      Addy Dan Mike Roy Sam Tommy
Addy    -1  -1    1   0   0     0
Dan      0   1    1   0  -1     0
Mike     0   0    0   1  -1     0
Roy      1   1   -1  -1   0     0
Sam     -1   0    0   0   1     0
Tommy    0   0    0   0   0     0
```