# Join two adjacency matrices and retain values

Tags: r, matrix, adjacency-matrix

#### Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295687/r-how-to-make-2-adjacency-matrices-compatible-to-eachother), is it possible to join two adjacency matrices, and retain the values of new rows and columns?

Building on the example in the reference, the union of `mat1` and `mat2` initializes values in newly added rows and columns with `0`. I want to initialize them with the value in the adjacency matrix, preserving that information.

```
> mat1
      Tommy Roy Addy Sam
Tommy     0   1    0  -1
Roy      -1  -1    1   0
Addy      1   0   -1   0
Sam       0   0   -1   1
> mat2
     Mike Roy Addy Sam Dan
Mike    0   1    0  -1   0
Roy    -1  -1    1   0   1
Addy    1   0   -1   0  -1
Sam     0   0   -1   1   0
Dan     1   0    0  -1   1

complete_matrix <- function(mat, ref) {
  dif <- setdiff(rownames(ref), rownames(mat))
  mat <- rbind(mat, matrix(0, length(dif), ncol(mat), dimnames = list(dif, NULL)))
  mat <- cbind(mat, matrix(0, nrow(mat), length(dif), dimnames = list(NULL, dif)))
  return(mat)
}

> complete_matrix(mat2, mat1)
      Mike Roy Addy Sam Dan Tommy
Mike     0   1    0  -1   0     0
Roy     -1  -1    1   0   1     0
Addy     1   0   -1   0  -1     0
Sam      0   0   -1   1   0     0
Dan      1   0    0  -1   1     0
Tommy    0   0    0   0   0     0
```

#### For example, I want `complete_matrix(mat2, mat1)` to yield the following (observe the `Tommy` row and column):

```
      Mike Roy Addy Sam Dan Tommy
Mike     0   1    0  -1   0     0
Roy     -1  -1    1   0   1     1
Addy     1   0   -1   0  -1     0
Sam      0   0   -1   1   0    -1
Dan      1   0    0  -1   1     0
Tommy    0   1    0  -1   0     0
```

---

`dput` for c&P:

```
mat1 <- structure(c(0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 
            -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Tommy", 
                                                                   "Roy", "Addy", "Sam"), c("Tommy", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam")))
mat2 <- structure(c(0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                    -1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                                       5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Mike", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam", "Dan"), 
                                                                                                             c("Mike", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam", "Dan")))
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a discrepancy? For example, what it the Addy/Sam value is 1 in `mat1` and 0 in `mat2`? (Or can we assume no discrepancy?)

Comment: @Gregor, this is an excellent question. For my purposes, there will never be a discrepancy. This is a small reprex for an enormous adjacency matrix calculation that I'm chunking into manageable pieces, then joining together into one enormous sparse matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using the `union` function of the `igraph` package, which would require to convert your matrices to graphs first and then convert back the resulting graph into a matrix:

```
library(igraph)

g1 = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat1,weighted=T)
g2 = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat2,weighted=T)
g3 = union(g1,g2)
```

`union` doesn't automatically merge the weights of g1 and g2, but keeps them as separate attributes `weight_1` and `weight_2`. We can combine them by taking the minimum value between the two weights, which, if there are no discrepancies between the 2 matrices, is just a way to merge them and remove the `NA` values.

```
E(g3)$weight = pmin(E(g3)$weight_1,E(g3)$weight_2,na.rm=T)
res = as.matrix(as_adj(g3,attr="weight"))

      Tommy Roy Addy Sam Mike Dan
Tommy     0   1    0  -1    0   0
Roy      -1  -1    1   0   -1   1
Addy      1   0   -1   0    1  -1
Sam       0   0   -1   1    0   0
Mike      0   1    0  -1    0   0
Dan       0   0    0  -1    1   1
```

Answer (score 3):

I would:

1. turn the matrices into individual pair-matrices (i.e. pair-value), i.e. matrix to long
2. bind them,
3. decide what to do for repeated pairs (here I just take first value...)
4. then spread to wide back.

Update: would probably run `distinct()` and add *value* in: `group_by(ind_1, ind_2, value)`. Plus fill with 0 in `spread()`?

Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mat1 <- structure(c(0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 
                    -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Tommy", 
                                                                           "Roy", "Addy", "Sam"), c("Tommy", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam")))
mat2 <- structure(c(0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                    -1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                                       5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Mike", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam", "Dan"), 
                                                                                                             c("Mike", "Roy", "Addy", "Sam", "Dan")))

mat1_l <- mat1 %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "ind_1") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  gather(ind_2, value, -ind_1)

mat2_l <- mat2 %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "ind_1") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  gather(ind_2, value, -ind_1)


rbind(mat1_l, mat2_l) %>% 
  group_by(ind_1, ind_2) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(ind_2, value)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   ind_1  Addy   Dan  Mike   Roy   Sam Tommy
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 Addy     -1    -1     1     0     0     1
#> 2 Dan       0     1     1     0    -1    NA
#> 3 Mike      0     0     0     1    -1    NA
#> 4 Roy       1     1    -1    -1     0    -1
#> 5 Sam      -1     0     0     0     1     0
#> 6 Tommy     0    NA    NA     1    -1     0
```

Comment: This works as well. Although I didn't mention it in the problem, I need an approach that works with sparse matrices due to memory issues. Thanks for this answer though!